# Casting an object to its original class

Tags: java, casting

To avoid having to do this:

```
if (obj instanceof Class) {
    someHandlingMethod((Class) obj);
}
else if (obj instanceof AnotherClass) {
    someHandlingMethod((AnotherClass) obj);
}
```

Is it possible to automatically cast an Object to its known class as stated by `obj.getClass().getName()`?

Second to that, is it neat and reliable? Or would it simply be better to use the "Chain of Responsibility" or "Handler" pattern?

#### For context:

The object received in my program is an object read from a ObjectInputStream transmitted over a network. All the objects received are of type 'Message', then I have several subclasses for types of message (such as AuthenticateRequest, ViewRequest). I want to handle these differently.

Comment: Have you tried generics?

Comment: I doubt generics would help me at all - the handling process is different for each type of object, so I'd still have to check each object's type.

Comment: You cannot cast to a class known only by a string value (i.e., `obj.getClass().getName()`). There are probably (almost certainly) cleaner ways of organizing your code than an `if...else` chain of `instanceof` tests. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok, because I was wondering why you were converting objects to the Object type, and usually that is due to the use of ArrayLists and stuff.

Comment: It is not a good idea to do so. It would be better  to create a Map<Class,Handler>. You will get the concrete Handler implementation by the object class and peform all actions that you need.

Comment: @CJxD - Once you have the class object, you still can't use that to cast. You can use Peter's reflection method. But again, what are you actually trying to accomplish? It may be that you can use a generic interface or a visitor pattern to advantage here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called a dynamic invocation.  The closest thing you can do is to use reflection.

```
Method method = getClass().getMethod("someHandlingMethod", obj.getClass());
method.invoke(this, obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cast` method that a Class object has:

```
Class clazz = obj.getClass();
clazz.cast(obj);
```

Another option: If you have access to `someHandlingMethod` code, you can add a parameter of type `Class` and pass the `obj.getClass()` to it.

```
public void someHandlingMethod(...., Class clazz);

public void someHandlingMethod(...., AnotherClass clazz);
```

You don't need to use this parameter. This will just allow you to call the correcto overloading.

Comment: This doesn't accomplish anything...after you call `clazz.cast(obj)`, what type of object is it?

Comment: I was not sure exactly what OP tries to accomplish but this is why I added my edit about overloading.

Comment: Can you use Method m = class.getDeclaredMethod("someHandlingMethod"); m.invoke(p);

Comment: Throwiing away the result of `Class.cast()` accomplishes exactly nothing. Answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the Visitor Pattern. Too well-known to need explanation here. See the Gang of Four book, or Wikipedia.

Comment: "Too well-known" - Apparently not.

Comment: @gourabix If by that remark you mean that you personally don't know about it, see the resources I mentioned. If you mean something else please explain.